# No properties are available on my Flutter Project using Material

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am in the process of updating a Flutter project from v2 to v3 and running into some weird issues. Everywhere anything Material related is being used, i get this prop does not exist. Here are some examples:

```
_uiViewPort(MaterialApp(
        home: StreamBuilder<bool>(
            stream: _authenticationService.loginStatusChangeStream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.data == true) {
                return Scaffold(
                  key: locator<DialogService>().scaffoldKey,
                  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
                  drawer: DrawerView(),
                  appBar: AppBarCustom(),
                  body: _initializeViewPort(),
                  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationView(),
                );
              }
              return Scaffold(
                resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
                body: _initializeViewPort(),
                bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationView(),
              );
            }),
      ));
```

I get The named parameter `home` isn't defined and The named parameter `stream` isn't defined, etc. etc.

This is the same for other fields too like:

```
Text(
          title,
          style: AppTheme.instance
              .textStyleSmall(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
        ),
```

It tells me that style is not defined. I upgraded the project to current Flutter and am trying to remediate all the errors.

Can anyone help me out at all? It seems like Material just isn't installed. But I don't get an error when importing it at the top of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try running

`flutter clean  flutter pub get`

if you are using android studio do file -> Invalidate cache and restart (find this at top bar)

Comment: I'm using vs code, but i'll give android studio a try. I did those steps and I'm still getting the same errors

Comment: make sure you have imported 'material.dart'; your code snipped is very small but should not be having this issue if possible share output from `flutter doctor`

Answer (score 0):

make sure to `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';` at top of your file